# User with multiple companies (different type)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, laravel

I built an application in Laravel that is a simple CRUD app. Now im struggling with migrations a bit.

User belongs to Company. Company can have many users.

Company type can be Supplier, Customer or Internal.
All 3 of company types have different fields. For example

> Supplier table contains: company_name, incoterm, payment_term,
> business type...etc
>
> Customer table contains: company_name, artwork, discount,
> target_margin... etc
>
> Internal table contains only company_name, updated_at and created_at
> fields.

So all of thame have company_name field, all other fields are different.

When user is logged in i want to be able to recognize is he supplier/customer or internal.
I want to be able to say `Supplier::find($id)->name` which should return me name of company.
`Supplier::find($id)->users` should return all users that supplier have. Same for customer, same for internal.

i'm not sure should i have user_type column in users table that will declare is user supplier/customer on internal or what should i do?

I was thinking about something like this :

Tables

User:

```
id
name
last_name
company_type
company_id
```

Supplier:

```
id
company_name
incoterm
payment_term
business type
```

Customer:

```
company_name 
artwork
discount 
target_margin
```

Internal:

```
company_name
```

Example of user table:

```
-
id: 1
name: "Aleksandar"
last_name: "Alex"
email: "alex@admin.com"
password: "$2y$10$4cYfe/J71VoCib.esHasWud7ueRHURMmcaqSECBJjNJ.y05qtXYXO"
company_type: "\\App\\Model\\Supplier"
company_id: 1
-
id: 2
name: "Another"
last_name: "User"
email: "user@admin.com"
password: "$2y$10$4cYfe/J71VoCib.esHasWud7ueRHURMmcaqSECBJjNJ.y05qtXYXO"
company_type: "\\App\\Model\\Customer"
company_id: 1
-
id: 3
name: "Internal"
last_name: "User"
email: "user@admin.com"
password: "$2y$10$4cYfe/J71VoCib.esHasWud7ueRHURMmcaqSECBJjNJ.y05qtXYXO"
company_type: "\\App\\Model\\Internal"
company_id: 1
```

After i have this i can do something like `user.company_type::find($id)` and i will get everything from Supplier/Customer or Internal with given $id.

Is this right way to do it ?  If yes then how can i get all user from supplier N? `Supplier::find($id)->users` or in future `Supplier::find($id)->posts` will require additional eloquent filter because company_id in users can be 1 for Supplier,Customer or Internal as on example from above.

Edit:
I'm using Laravel v6.18.35

Comment: Your way is correct way

Comment: Are you using Eloquent ? What version of laravel are you using? Are you already using [polymorphic relations](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-polymorphic-relations) . Storing the php class in your database seems a bad practice to me, you might want to use a [morph map](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#custom-polymorphic-types) to avoid this.

Comment: @hsibboni yes, i'm using Eloquent. Laravel v6.18.35. No I'm not using polymorphic relations right now. Did not know about them to be honest.

Comment: @mare96 's answer should help you, this seems to be the way to go, good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@hsibboni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7473172/hsibboni) mentioned probably what you need is [polymorphic relations](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-polymorphic-relations).

So you will need something like this in your models:

**User**

```
public function company()
{
    return $this->morphTo('company', 'company_type', 'company_id', 'id');
}
```

**Supplier, Customer and Internal**

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->morphMany(User::class, 'company', 'company_type', 'company_id', 'id');
}
```

And when you load relation `company` on User you will get the company of that user, also if you load relation `users` for Supplier, Customer, or Internal you will get Users that belong to them.

I think this is what you need.

Good luck!